# NuxtJs axios module global config

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I need to set global configuration for [@nuxt/axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/).

For example I need default Content-Type, Accept, Authorization header etc. and other configurations for all of my API calls. Is there any way to add these settings globally in nuxt to avoid repetition of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend
You can create a plugin and dump your axios configuration there like this
`nuxt.config.js`

```json
export default {
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/axios'
  ]
}
```

`/plugins/axios.js`

```js
export default ({ $axios, $config: { baseUrlIam, secretToken } }) => {
  $axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrlIam
  $axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = secretToken
}
```

Also, [`setHeader`](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers#setheader) may be useful.